# Angular 9 upgrade causes @types errors during compile

Tags: angular, angular9

Recently upgraded my project from angular 7 to 9 after following the steps from official angular guide for upgrade. I'm getting alot of @types errors when i try to `ng serve` the app.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:16:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: beforeAll, beforeEach, afterAll, afterEach, describe, fdescribe, xdescribe, it, fit, xit, expect, clock, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL, CustomMatcherFactory, CustomEqualityTester

16 type ImplementationCallback = (() => Promise<any>) | ((done: DoneFn) => void);
   ~~~~

  node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:34:1
    34 declare var beforeAll: jest.Lifecycle;
       ~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:190:15 - error TS2428: All declarations of 'ArrayContaining' must have identical type parameters.

190     interface ArrayContaining<T> {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:197:15 - error TS2428: All declarations of 'ObjectContaining' must have identical type parameters.

197     interface ObjectContaining<T> {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:245:9 - error TS2687: All declarations of 'message' must have identical modifiers.

245         message?: string;
            ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:34:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: beforeAll, beforeEach, afterAll, afterEach, describe, fdescribe, xdescribe, it, fit, xit, expect, clock, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL, CustomMatcherFactory, CustomEqualityTester

34 declare var beforeAll: jest.Lifecycle;
   ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:16:1
    16 type ImplementationCallback = (() => Promise<any>) | ((done: DoneFn) => void);
       ~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:1331:46 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ArrayContaining<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1331     function arrayContaining(sample: any[]): ArrayContaining;
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:1332:45 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ObjectContaining<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1332     function objectContaining(sample: any): ObjectContaining;
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:1358:15 - error TS2428: All declarations of 'ArrayContaining' must have identical type parameters.

1358     interface ArrayContaining {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:1364:15 - error TS2428: All declarations of 'ObjectContaining' must have identical type parameters.

1364     interface ObjectContaining {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:1472:9 - error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.

1472         [index: string]: CustomMatcherFactory;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:1492:9 - error TS2687: All declarations of 'message' must have identical modifiers.

1492         message: string | (() => string);
             ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:1492:9 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'message' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'string | (() => string)'.

1492         message: string | (() => string);
             ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:245:9
    245         message?: string;
                ~~~~~~~
    'message' was also declared here.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:1497:9 - error TS2375: Duplicate number index signature.

1497         [n: number]: T;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts:56:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'assert'.

56     export = assert;
                ~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/ts3.7/assert.d.ts:56:14
    56     export = assert;
                    ~~~~~~
    'assert' was also declared here.
node_modules/@types/node/globals.global.d.ts:1:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'global' must be of type 'Global & typeof globalThis', but here has type 'Global'.

1 declare var global: NodeJS.Global;
              ~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/ts3.5/globals.global.d.ts:1:13
    1 declare var global: NodeJS.Global & typeof globalThis;
                  ~~~~~~
    'global' was also declared here.
node_modules/@types/node/ts3.7/assert.d.ts:56:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'assert'.

56     export = assert;
                ~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts:56:14
    56     export = assert;
                    ~~~~~~
    'assert' was also declared here.
```

Here is my tsconfig
**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/@types",
    "node_modules/uicomponents/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/mfa-ui/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/inbox-notification/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

in **package.json** i have following relevant dev dependencies

```
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/chai-as-promised": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/cucumber": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
    "@types/fs-extra": "4.0.3",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/klaw-sync": "1.1.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.0",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^1.6.7",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.3",
    "typescript": "3.8.3",
```

**Things i have tried:**.
deleting node_modules, package-lock.json and run `npm cache verify` multiple times. 
Remove all app related code under src to test if it compiles which has been unsuccessful.
Also tried putting explicit types to use in tsconfig which did not work for me.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "types" : ["node"]
 }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look into changes in package.json. most likely some dependencies were updated but related "@types/*" dependencies weren't